# Passing Database Password to Dataproc PySpark batch job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-secret-manager

I want to create a pyspark job, and I want to have two separate environments: sandbox and production. Based on the environment it runs in, the script should connect either to the sandbox or production postgres database that runs on Google Cloud SQL.

For all the other functionalities required (things that run in Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) I managed to separate the environments using pydantic settings with the following class:

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    db_user: str = Field()
    db_pass: str = Field()
    db_name: str = Field()
    db_host: str = Field()

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
```

These values are passed in as environment variables through the Secret Manager, so only requests from within Google Cloud Datacenters access the sensible data. I did not find a suitable way to pass secrets to a Dataproc batch job, the best alternative I found are properties (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/properties), that become environment variables.

Functionally I can simply set all the variables I need using the properties, but it would mean sending all my database information over the network from my computer where I launch the job to GCP, which looks like a security risk.

Is there a better way to separate sandbox and production environments in dataproc, or can I somehow access secrets when deploying a dataproc batch job?